# Convert dummies into actual count in R

Tags: r

I'm new here, a beginner in R, and struggling with the following. I have a large clickstream database with pagepaths from multiple sessions. I classified the pages into categories and counted the number of pages visited in that category.

```
  SessionID category     count       
1    101     homepage      1        
2    101     productpage   6        
3    101     searchpage    4          
4    102     homepage      3         
6    102     searchpage    5
```

I know that by using the code below, I can create dummies.

```
df %>%
  group_by(SessionID) %>%
  mutate(homepage = +(any(grepl('homepage', category))), 
         productpage = +(any(grepl('productpage', category))),
         searchpage = +(any(grepl('search', category))))

   SessionID category     count    homepage    productpage    searchpage     
1    101     homepage      1          1            1              1
2    101     productpage   6          1            1              1 
3    101     searchpage    4          1            1              1 
4    102     homepage      3          1            0              1
6    102     searchpage    5          1            0              1
```

But instead of the 1/0, I want the actual number of pages visited in that category, so that I can filter out the duplicate rows, and delete the category column, leaving:

```
     SessionID     homepage    productpage    searchpage     
1      101             1            6              4
2      102             3            0              5
```

There is probably an easier way to do this but for me, the important thing is that I am left with the output above. I would be nice if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=category,values_from=count,values_fill=list(count=0))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  SessionID homepage productpage searchpage
      <int>    <int>       <int>      <int>
1       101        1           6          4
2       102        3           0          5
```

The data:

```
df = structure(list(SessionID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L), category = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("homepage", "productpage", "searchpage"
), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `dplyr` or even whole `tidyverse` to work with your data.

The solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = count) %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

where `data` is:

```
data <- tibble(SessionID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102),
              category = c("homepage", "productpage", "searchpage", "homepage", "searchpage"),
              count = c(1, 6, 4, 3, 5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(count ~ SessionID + category, df)
#        category
#SessionID homepage productpage searchpage
#   101        1           6          4
#   102        3           0          5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(SessionID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L), category = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("homepage", "productpage", "searchpage"
), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "6"))
```